# how to solve this weird old windows 7 internet access trouble?

Tags: windows, windows-7, networking

I have a **weird** problem with my windows 7 internet connectivity. I even do not know how to explain the problem!

I can connect to our local network without any problems (both through ethernet and WLAN), and I can ping my gateway (ADSL modem) but there is a **serious problem** accessing the internet:

most times there is no internet access at all. but suddenly I can access the internet for a very short period of time, say 10 seconds! then again the internet access is lost.

for the rest of the time, I can only access some very specific handful of websites including Google, StackOverflow, Wikipedia(sometime only Google).

the problem gets weirder when I notice that when Windows 7 is connected to the local network **other devices that were working properly before now have an internet access problem!!** (when I connect this Windows to our local network I hear the voices of my brother, sisters, and my mother coming from other rooms that complaining about internet problem!) when I disconnect this cursed Windows 7 from the local network other device's internet access problem goes away!

**in all cases, the kind of errors that I get is network time-out**

I am facing this problem for 4-5 years!! yes, years! (my main OS is Linux, I do not use Windows that much, only for some video games and graphic software, but recently I need it for my work :( too bad!)

I tried so many times to solve this problem but each time I failed, now I wanted to post my problem here for my final attempt (and curiosity!).

what I have tried in these years:

uninstall/reinstall ethernet/WLAN adapter drivers(god knows how many times!)

reset all network-related things! (like flushing DNS, in fact, I tried most of google search results for "how to reset Windows 7 network", "how to fully/completely reset Windows 7 network" and similar)

disable/reenable windows firewall/windows defender(I have no other firewall/security software)

**all with no success.**

what do you suggest?!

installing new windows is not an option! (first I need to know the problem, then maybe I install windows 10!!)

thank you all for reading this long question(sorry for bad English, I wish I could write better to express my misery better that this problem faced me, but you guess)

Comment: The best way to solve a problem like this is to perform an in-place upgrade of Windows 7 or simply upgrade to Windows 10.  You have not provided enough information to diagnose the cause of your problem.

Comment: an upgrade is not an option for now

Comment: I am not sure why an easy upgrade is not a option. Nonetheless, since you have done the normal network repairs without success, do a Windows 7 Repair Install.   https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html